# how to implement RESideMedu for ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad, xib

I have included `RESidemenu` into my project . I am creating iPhone and iPad xibs but only iPhone xibs are running. How to add iPad xibs to `RESidemenu`?

anybody know that....thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code it is working in my project

```
DEMOLeftMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController;
    DEMORightMenuViewController *rightMenuViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[DEMOFirstViewController alloc] init]];

    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        leftMenuViewController = [[DEMOLeftMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DEMOFirstViewController_iphone" bundle:nil];
        rightMenuViewController = [[DEMORightMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DEMORightMenuViewController_iphone" bundle:nil];

    }else{
        leftMenuViewController = [[DEMOLeftMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DEMOFirstViewController_ipad" bundle:nil];
         rightMenuViewController = [[DEMORightMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DEMORightMenuViewController_ipad" bundle:nil];

    }

    RESideMenu *sideMenuViewController = [[RESideMenu alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController
                                                                    leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                                   rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];
    sideMenuViewController.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Stars"];
    sideMenuViewController.menuPreferredStatusBarStyle = 1; // UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
    sideMenuViewController.delegate = self;
    sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowOpacity = 0.6;
    sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowRadius = 12;
    sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowEnabled = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = sideMenuViewController;
```

Comment: i am asking how to add internal pages in the      [self.sideMenuViewController setContentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[WPoverview alloc] init]]animated:YES];

Comment: set it like  NSString *strNibname;
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        strNibname=@"WPoverview_iphone"; // Set here iphone nib name
    }else{
        strNibname=@"WPoverview_ipad"; // Set here ipad nib name
    }
    [self.sideMenuViewController setContentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[WPoverview alloc] initWithNibName:strNibname bundle:nil]]animated:YES];